# Laravel Authentication doesn't work properly

Tags: php, laravel, session, authentication

I  created login form and implemented authentication for admin side of website.

Login form works perfectly  fine ,however i can reach to admin/index without logging . I tried  middleware but even if i log in it won't let me to reach admin/index. What did i miss ?

Here is my route ,

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
   Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
   Route::get('index', array('as' => 'admin', 'uses' => 'AdminController@admin'));
   Route::get('doctors', array('as' => 'doctors.index', 'uses' => 'DoctorsController@index'));
   Route::post('doctorstore', array('as' => 'doctors.store', 'uses' => 'DoctorsController@store'));
   Route::post('doctorsmail', array('as' => 'doctors.mail', 'uses' => 'DoctorsController@update'));
});

Route::get('/', array('as' => 'getlogin', 'uses' =>'AdminController@getLogin'));
Route::post('/', array('as' => 'postlogin', 'uses' =>'AdminController@postLogin'));
```

and this is my controller

```
public function getLogin()
     return view('admin.login');

public function postLogin(Request $request){

    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => Request::input('email'), 'password' => Request::input('password')])){
        return redirect()->route('admin');
    }else{
        return 'not entered ';
    }
}

public function getRegister()
{
    return view('admin.register');
}

protected function postRegister(Request $request)
{
    return User::create([
        'email' => $request['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($request['password']),
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Use https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/quickstart-intermediate and see what's different from yours

Answer (score 0):

You're never closing your route group:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
   Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
       Route::get('index', array('as' => 'admin', 'uses' => 'AdminController@admin'));
       Route::get('doctors', array('as' => 'doctors.index', 'uses' => 'DoctorsController@index'));
       Route::post('doctorstore', array('as' => 'doctors.store', 'uses' => 'DoctorsController@store'));
       Route::post('doctorsmail', array('as' => 'doctors.mail', 'uses' => 'DoctorsController@update'));
   }); // You were missing this
});
```

Comment: i fixed it but nothing  changed